# Can I use pngs from apps like picsart in a portfolio?

Tags: copyright, legal, licensing, portfolio

I am looking to make my portfolio for college but a lot of the pngs and images I use are from picsart or images from the internet? Could I use them? I'm unsure how to credit things from picsart, I'm not a digital artist so how would I use images?

Answer (score 1):

Check the terms of service...

> Picsart Content

> We grant to you a limited, non-exclusive, non-transferable, non-sublicensable, revocable license to reproduce, display, and perform Content owned by us, including any content generated by an artificial intelligence model, or our licensors (“Picsart Content”) only for your personal and non-commercial use and only as permitted by the functionality of the Service.

> We grant to you a limited, non-exclusive, non-transferable, non-sublicensable, revocable license to reproduce, display, perform, and create derivative works of Picsart Content identified as being available for commercial use on the Service (“Commercial Use Picsart Content”), and distribute your derivative works that incorporate Commercial Use Picsart Content, for any purpose including commercial purposes, only as permitted by the functionality of the Service.

So it *seems* you have permission to use "content" provided by Picsart.

A portfolio is typically a "commercial use" though. So you'd need to ensure any content you've used has that permissible hashtag apparently (`#freeforbusiness`).

I'm not a lawyer.. I have *no clue* what type of portfolio you may be creating and I'm not familiar with Picsart. I merely found their TOS.

No clue if you are... but be careful if you are creating a "design" portfolio and the Picsart content is all based on their provided templates. Template use doesn't really show any design abilities. And showing too much work based on templates *may* be detrimental.